# Learning pyramid (python) and am struggling with the @view_config decorator. Should it just work out of the box?

Tags: python, decorator, pyramid

I am still learning pyramid, and I am at a point where I am trying to learn how to use decorators.  Below is a copy of my test view callable.

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.renderers import render_to_response

def my_blog(request):
    return {'project':'tricky'}

@view_config( renderer='templates/foo.pt' )
def foo_blog(request):
    return {'name':'tricky'}
```

From what I can understand about the view_config decorator, it can be used to set application configurations without actually setting them in the config file.  In the case of this example, I am setting the renderer to be templates/foo.pt.  This does not ever work.

However, if I set renderer in the config file (**init**.py) as such:

```
config.add_route( 'foo_blog' , '/blog/{foo}' ,  view='tricky.views.Blog.blog.foo_blog' renderer='tricky:templates/mytemplate.pt' )
```

it will work.

Am I doing something wrong that is preventing me from being able to use the decorator.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for the configurations added via @view_config to work, you need to call config.scan() at some point.